# Failing a unit test if an exception is thrown in another thread

Tags: unit-testing, junit, testng, hamcrest, assertj

Currently, whenever I need to fail a test in response to an exception thrown in another thread, I write something like this:

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static java.util.Arrays.asList;
import static java.util.Collections.synchronizedList;
import static org.testng.Assert.fail;

public final class T {
  @Test
  public void testFailureFromLambda() throws Throwable {
    final List<Throwable> errors = synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    asList("0", "1", "2").parallelStream().forEach(s -> {
      try {
        /*
         * The actual code under test here.
         */
        throw new Exception("Error " + s);
      } catch (final Throwable t) {
        errors.add(t);
      }
    });

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      errors.forEach(Throwable::printStackTrace);

      final Throwable firstError = errors.iterator().next();
      fail(firstError.getMessage(), firstError);
    }
  }
}
```

A synchronized list may be replaced with an `AtomicReference<Throwable>`, but in general the code remains pretty much the same.

Is there any standard (and less verbose) way of doing the same using any of test frameworks available in *Java* ([*TestNG*](http://testng.org/doc/), [*JUnit*](http://junit.org/), [*Hamcrest*](http://hamcrest.org/), [*AssertJ*](https://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/), etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default TestNG fails a test method when an exception is thrown from it. I believe the same thing happens with JUnit as well, wherein it marks a test as `errored`, if it throws an unexpected exception.

If you are to be dealing with `Streams`, then you would need to wrap it up within a `RuntimeException` variant, so that Java doesn't complain. TestNG would automatically fail the test.

Here's a sample :

```
@Test
public void testFailureFromLambdaRefactored() {
    asList("0", "1", "2").parallelStream().forEach(s -> {
        try {
        /*
        * The actual code under test here.
        */
            if (s.equals("2")) {
                throw new Exception("Error " + s);
            }
        } catch (final Throwable t) {
            throw new RuntimeException(t);
        }
    });
}
```

This was for scenarios that involve lambdas and streams. In general if you would like to know about an exception that happens in a new thread spun off from a `@Test` method, then you would need to use `ExecutorService`.

Here's a sample :

```
@Test
public void testFailureInAnotherThread() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    List<String> list = asList("0", "1", "2");
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    List<Future<Void>> futures = service.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new Worker(list)));
    for (Future future : futures) {
        future.get();
    }

}

public static class Worker implements Callable<Void> {
    private List<String> list;

    public Worker(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        for (String s : list) {
            if (s.equals("2")) {
                throw new Exception("Error " + s);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to prevent failing the whole test and continue soft assertions if an exception is thrown in one of the soft assertions?

Comment: @enissay - By default `SoftAssertions` fail a test only after all the assertions have been validated.

Comment: that's not my experience with it. Maybe I'm doing sth wrong. I have posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46681601/3619769), hopefully you'd be able to help me out :)